# Zipping a file in a directory using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I'm trying to zip a file which is currently in a directory of mine,
i have used the code below to achieve that to no avail.

i was told to use zipfile and it doesnt seem to be working for me, it creates an empty zip file.

```
19:52 ~/mysite/static/downloads $ ls                                                
2830854  5378949 
>>> import zipfile                                                                  
>>> import os                                                                       
>>> os.getcwd()                                                                     
'/home/KindredBay/mysite/static/downloads'                                          
>>> zip = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
>>> zip                                                                             
<zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7f52f2150e10>                                          
>>> zip.write(os.getcwd()+'/', '2830854')
>>>                                                                                 
[5]+  Stopped                 python                                                
19:56 ~/mysite/static/downloads $ ls                                                
2830854  5378949  test.zip                                                          
19:56 ~/mysite/static/downloads $
```

Comment: That is about a file structure, this is not.

Comment: You have to call `ZipFile.write()` each individual file in the directory, even if there's only one.